# How to place a link from a txt file to another txt file but in a specific place with bash scripting?

Tags: css, bash, shell, scripting, sh

I have a css file which is this 1.css

```
/* CSS variables
   Generated by 'wal' */
:root {
**    --wallpaper: url("/home/x/.local/share/wallpaper/wall.png");**

    /* Special */
    --background: #10171d;
    --foreground: #daccd3;
    --cursor: #daccd3;
```

I want to extract that url link which is in wallpaper url " ". and want to put it in this css file which is this

```
@-moz-document url(about:home), url(about:newtab), url(about:privatebrowsing) {
    .click-target-container *, .top-sites-list * {
        color: #fff !important ;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #222 !important ;
    }
 
    body::before {
        content: "" ;
        z-index: -1 ;
        position: fixed ;
        top: 0 ;
        left: 0 ;
        **background: #f9a no-repeat url("want to put that link here") center ;**
        background-size: cover ;
        width: 100vw ;
        height: 100vh ;
    }
}
```

I want the link to be in background url of the 2nd css file

I tried some of this commands

```
awk 'NR==4 { print $2 }' colors.css > 1.txt
cat '1,txt' |sed 's/;.*//' > 2.txt
```

to extract the link from first file. But I don't know how to import that link to the 2nd css file at the exact place

Comment: Please don't put `**` highlighting in code blocks, put valid code. If you want to annotate it, use the language's comment syntax.

Comment: FYI, `awk` can do substitutions in strings, you don't need `sed` for that.

Comment: please update the question to show the expected result (with the actual URL displayed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `awk` result in a variable. Then use that variable in `sed` to update the CSS file.

```
url=$(awk '/--wallpaper:/ {print($2)}' colors.css)
sed -E -i '/background:/s#(background: .* )url\([^)]*\)(.*;)#\1'"${url%;}"'\2#' second.css
```

The `%` parameter expansion operator can be used to remove the trailing `;` in `$url`.

Comment: after executing it I am getting this error :
sed: -e expression #1, char 61: Unmatched ) or \)

Comment: I edited the answer a few minutes ago to remove an extra `)`. Did you copy it before I fixed that?

Comment: I just fixed another mistake -- `${url%;}` needs to be in double quotes.]

Comment: it showing this error :
sed: -e expression #1, char 54: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Forgot that the pathname contains `/` characters, so we have to use a different delimiter in the `s` command.